# Google places autocomplete - location and radius not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Im trying to set the google places autocomplete to sort the results from the nearest to a point. I have a code like this...

```js
var defaultPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(49.227463, 16.546097);

var optionsAuto = {
    location: defaultPlace,
    radius: 20000,
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'cz'
    }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( inputStart, optionsAuto );
```

the types and componentRestrictions works great but the location and radius doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

It states:

> radius | Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return Place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified.

It sound like you want the optional parameter: rankby=distance:

> rankby | distance. This option sorts results in ascending order by their distance from the specified location. Ranking results by distance will set a fixed search radius of 50km. One or more of keyword, name, or types is required.

Which is also available in the [javascript service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search.html)

Comment: I think the problem is that you are expecting the autocomplete results to be ordered by distance. That is not supported.  The only [componentRestriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions) for autocomplete is country

Comment: well that is the problem...I tried to use the bounds option and the results are now much more relevant to the location so I guess I will stick with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to return places just in radius you need to set *strictbounds*  to true.

The main problem for me right now is that Autocomplete doesn't have rankBy.
see [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that someone may not be agree with me but In my case i defined the radius without quotes i.e like below

```
 var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
        bounds: map.getBounds(),
    radius: 2000,
    zoom: 15,
    types: ['restaurant']
  };
```

So it didn't make any difference on radius and showed the result independent of radius but when i applied quotes on it , radius parameter seems to be working

```
 var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
        bounds: map.getBounds(),
    radius: '2000',
    zoom: 15,
    types: ['restaurant']
  };
```