# How can i force google autocomplete to not include any results that out for requested radius?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I've got a problem with Google Autocomplete rest api.

I need to return predictions only for certain radius, but "radius" parameter doesn't filter incorrect results. Currently I get results from another cities and even other countries.

How can i force google autocomplete to not include any results that out of requested radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` and `radius` parameters only act as a bias to the results, there is currently no way to restrict results to a specific radius. You can however restrict results to a specific country by passing the `components` parameter as detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests).

If you use the `location`, `radius` and `component` parameters you will most likely get the desired results.

An example search for Eiffel Tower, with a lat,lng location in Melbourne, Australia, radius 50km, and country restrict to Australia returns "Eiffel Tower Chocolate & Confectionery" as the real Eiffel tower is not within the radius or in the country that the request is restricted to:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Eiffel+Tower&location=-37.816836,144.963123&radius=50000&components=country:au&sensor=false&key=your_api_key

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional parameter `radius`.

> radius — The distance (in meters) within which to return Place
>   results. Note that setting a radius biases results to the indicated
>   area, but may not fully restrict results to the specified area. See
>   [Location Biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#location_biasing).

Comment: I'm already using radius. It doesn't filter results that are out of that radius.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to force this is to do the filtering yourself in the result array that you get when performing the search. I haven't used the Autocomplete API, but it seems you are using the Maps API to search? In that case, you get [a GeocoderResult object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=sv#GeocoderResult) which you can inspect the coordinates for the items, and compare them to your desired point and radius.

A bit hacky, but quite straightforward.

Comment: Autocomplete predictions doesn't contain location information. Also there is only 5 prediction. And usually 3 of them incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This example (uses the Google Maps API v3 places library):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search.html

from this answer:

[Google places autocomplete - location and radius not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810810/google-places-autocomplete-location-and-radius-not-working)

uses rankby=distance

You can process the results to remove any not within your desired radius.

Comment: there is no rankby option for autocomplete request