# Google Places API Radius

Tags: google-maps, google-places

Why does the Google Places API provide more Points of Interests (POI) by providing a smaller radius? The definition of radius is noted below:

**radius** — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to bias place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Results inside of this region will be ranked higher than results outside of the search circle; however, prominent results from outside of the search radius may be included.

When using the API I get significantly more POIs by providing a radius of 50 vs. 200 meters. What is the "bias" that is mentioned in the definition above? Does anyone know how the radius meter search may translate to a zoom level when using Google Maps? Any information provided would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That is an interesting question, I would have thought that changing map zoom depending on radius shouldn't be the case because it can give inaccurate results. But it seems like that is indeed the case. Hope someone knows more about this.

Comment: related question: [Google places autocomplete - location and radius not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810810/google-places-autocomplete-location-and-radius-not-working)